# spring servlet map to .html would respond works but map to non html ending url do not

Tags: java, spring, servlets, mapping

i have a spring servlet has a mapping file and in there i defined the url/controller mapping:

```
<prop key="/template.html">templateWebServiceController</prop>
```

from there if i were to test by my browser and goto localhost:8080/myapp/template.html,
it will call the the servlet

however, if i were to change the servlet mapping into:

```
<prop key="/template">templateWebServiceController</prop>
```

essentially taking out the .html, doing so (goto localhost:8080/myapp/template )
would not be able to invoke the servlet

am i missing something? or testing it wrong?

thanks!

Comment: did you try `template.form` with the config


`<prop key="/template">templateWebServiceController</prop>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring dispatcher servlet is mapped to a URL pattern in web.xml. In your case, it's probably for URLs ending in `.html`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you want Spring to accept other types of patterns (like `/template`), you have to change the mapping to something else OR add another servlet-mapping with another pattern.

For example, you can add a mapping with `<url-pattern>/template</url-pattern>` and your controller will be picked up. Or you can put `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and all URLs will be picked up by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a mapping for the DispatcherServlet

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and in your servlet config add

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Then you can also access the root url at localhost:8080/myapp/ and all other extensions etc